# Python how to use ctypes to get data from a Windows struct

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I'm trying to get data through a Windows API struct.  Specifically [WINDOWPOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-windowpos).  Honestly, I have no idea.  How do I get the x and y position of a folder using WINDOWPOS?  I have no code to share because I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Ctypes has pretty extensive documentation on what to do. Specifically, you first have to load the dynamic [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#loading-dynamic-link-libraries), which if it's part of the C runtime, will be msvcrt, but types are not stored in binary files (besides COM, but that's weird). Next, you need to define a [structure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions) for the type, and the functions you need to call (and modify the [restypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#return-types)).

Comment: That documentation, if carefully looked at, should tell you everything you need to know to start trying. In this case, for example, if you need `SetWindowPos`, you need `User32.dll`, not the traditional C runtime.

Comment: I have done a little work with ctypes before and can blindly stumble around the net and figure some things out, however, the documentation for "WINDOWPOS" doesn't give the .dll it's stored in, so I don't know which library to load.

Comment: Because it's a Structure: it isn't stored in a DLL. Type information isn't. You need the functions you want to call, which are stored in a DLL.

Comment: That's why I said "types are not stored in binary files (besides COM, but that's weird)."

Comment: Ooh.  Good to know.  Sorry, I read your post several times; I'm just a little confused.  Pretty new territory for me.  Forgive me for this question, but I can't retrieve the folder positions for use later?  I'm writing a script that requires to close Explorer.  I want to restore the open folders immediately after I restart Explorer.

Comment: You can, as long as you use `GetWindowRect`. You need to learn the Windows API if you're going to want to do this.

Comment: `GetWindowRect`, gotcha.  Thanks for your patience and help, @Alexander Huszagh.  Hopefully I can do what I want now.

Comment: No worries, glad to help. Just, I recommend trying some sample code, and then if you have an issue, ask a more targeted question here. Feel free to tag me. The [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect) docs are quite good, which will link the required DLLs at the bottom.

Comment: If I run into any trouble, I will come prepared with specific code that is causing issues.  I will also do my due diligence with the MSDN docs first (and Duck Duck Go) prior to posting.  It's just with my original post, I didn't even know where to begin.  I have very limited experience with the Windows API and `ctypes` in general, so I was utterly lost.  But you put me on the right track, @Alexander Huszagh.